# Render different sidebar for each navbar item onClick in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

I am using **react-router-dom** to manage routes in my application. I need to have a static navbar where clicking a particular item will render respective sidebar. I am using **react-bootstrap** to implement navbar.
[Here is the main "Home" page nav link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN8PI.png)
[Here is the "About" page nav link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpssz.png)

*All click events are working fine.*

**Here is the problem** - when i am going back using the browser's back button,

1. Sidebar routes aren't highlighting.
2. If "About" page is clicked just after clicking any routes from the "Home" page, then pressing back button will display nothing.[check it out here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGXRp.png)

Here are main files including the navigation -

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { NavigationBar } from "./components/NavigationBar";
import { Home } from "./pages/Home";
import { About } from "./pages/About";
import { Book } from "./pages/Book";
import { Camera } from "./pages/Camera";
import { NoMatch } from "./pages/NoMatch";
import SidebarHome from "./components/SidebarHome";
import SidebarAbout from "./components/SidebarAbout";

function App() {
  console.log(window.location.pathname);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <NavigationBar />

        {window.location.pathname === "/" ? (
          <>
            <SidebarHome />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/clock" component={About} />
              <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <SidebarAbout />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/about" component={Camera} />
              <Route path="/book" component={Book} />
            </Switch>
          </>
        )}
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

NavigationBar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar, Form, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Styles = styled.div`
  .navbar { background-color: #222; }
  a, .navbar-nav, .navbar-light .nav-link {
    color: #E892FF;
    &:hover { color: white; }
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color:grey;
    border-radius:10%;
    width:50px;
text-align:center;
    &:hover { color: white; }
  }
  .form-center {
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
  }
`;

export const NavigationBar = () => (
  <Styles>
    <Navbar >
      <Navbar.Brand href="/">T</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav"/>

      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav >
          <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href="/" >Home</Nav.Link></Nav.Item> 
          <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href="/about" >About</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  </Styles>
)
```

SidebarHome.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const StyledSideNav = styled.div`   
    position: fixed;     /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll and position relative to viewport) */
    height: 100%;
    width: 75px;     /* Set the width of the sidebar */
    z-index: 1;      /* Stay on top of everything */
    top: 3.4em;      /* Stay at the top */
    background-color: #222; /* Black */
    overflow-x: hidden;     /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 20px;
`;

class SideNav extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activePath: props.location.pathname,
            items: [
                {
                  path: '/', /* path is used as id to check which NavItem is active basically */
                  name: 'Home',
                  css: 'fa fa-home',
                  key: 1 /* Key is required, else console throws error. Does this please you Mr. Browser?! */
                },
                {
                  path: '/clock',
                  name: 'Clock',
                  css: 'fa fa-fw fa-clock',
                  key: 2
                },
                {
                  path: '/NoMatch',
                  name: 'NoMatch',
                  css: 'fas fa-hashtag',
                  key: 3
                },
              ]
        }
    }

    onItemClick = (path) => {
        this.setState({ activePath: path });
    }

    render() {
        const { items, activePath } = this.state;
        return(
            <StyledSideNav>
                {
                    items.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <NavItem 
                                path={item.path}
                                name={item.name}
                                css={item.css}
                                onItemClick={this.onItemClick}
                                active={item.path === activePath}
                                key={item.key}
                            />
                        );
                    })
                }
            </StyledSideNav>
        );
    }
}

const RouterSideNav = withRouter(SideNav);

const StyledNavItem = styled.div`
    height: 70px;
    width: 75px; /* width must be same size as NavBar to center */
    text-align: center; /* Aligns <a> inside of NavIcon div */
    margin-bottom: 0;   /* Puts space between NavItems */
    a {
        font-size: 2.7em;
        color: ${(props) => props.active ? "#fff" : "grey"};
        text-decoration: none; /* Gets rid of underlining of icons */

        // :hover {
        //     opacity: 0.7;
        // }  
    }
`;

class NavItem extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        const { path, onItemClick } = this.props;
        onItemClick(path);
    }

    render() {
        const { active } = this.props;
        return(
            <StyledNavItem active={active}>
                <Link to={this.props.path} className={this.props.css} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <NavIcon></NavIcon>
                </Link>
            </StyledNavItem>
        );
    }
}

const NavIcon = styled.div`

`;

export default class SidebarHome extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <RouterSideNav></RouterSideNav>
        );
    }
}
```

Earlier I used to work on applications containing single sidebar without a navbar. Therefore I am following pretty much the same flow that i am used to follow. If there is another smart and efficient way to implement this, please guide me through the proper workflow.

Comment: Have you tried using `NavLink` instead of `Link` from `react-router-dom` which has an "active" state when it is the currently matching route? I'm not sure about using the back button, but mixing navigation methodologies from both `react-bootstrap` ***and*** `react-router-dom` probably isn't helping here. Think you could create a working, *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue you see that we can inspect and debug live?